# Locating specific file types in a column

Tags: python, locate

One column in report is titled 'Filename' and there are several possible options 'xxxx.pdf', 'xxxx.Empty'.

How do I get Python to locate only files that are '.Empty' for example?

I've been trying the following code which doesn't produce an error but also brings up no results when it should

```
df3.loc[df3['Filename'] == '.Empty']
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: yea because there is no '.Empty' in your dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have a dataframe like this

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([['a.Empty'], ['b.pdf']], columns=['file'])
```

```
    file
0   a.Empty
1   b.pdf
```

To get all the files that are Empty use `str.contains`

```py
df[df['file'].str.contains('.Empty')]
```

```
    file
0   a.Empty
```

If you want all files except empty then

```py
df[~df['file'].str.contains('.Empty')]
```

```
    file
1   b.pdf
```